# Execution failed for task :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class

my build grandle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.kiry32.root.quizaia"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 13
            versionName "1.3.5"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
                'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        productFlavors {
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://dl.appnext.com/" }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.appnext.sdk:ads:2.+' // Mandatory
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0' // Mandatory
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

and other grandle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

How do I fix this error? Before I placed the appnext advertising it worked made me apk

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because appnext also has the google play services library inside it. 
Remove 
compile `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'` 
and only use the part of Google play services you really need. Just like you have added

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0' // Mandatory
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
```